# Can't complile MySQL Connector/J with JDK1.7

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, ant

I modified MySQL Connector/J and in my modification I used 2 jars ( built on JDK1.7 ).
When I tried to build the jdbc using ANT build I faced the following errors, I think this error happening because there is new methods in JDK1.7 added on the interfaces of the JDBC, and there some issues in compatibility with Generic syntax (), any advice please how I can build this JDBC using JDK1.7:

```
clean:
[delete] Deleting directory C:\Users\osbieh\Desktop\JDBC-Test\MySql_JDBC_OLD\build

-init-copy:
[mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\osbieh\Desktop\JDBC-Test\MySql_JDBC_OLD\build
 [exec] Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "svn": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
 [copy] Copying 235 files to C:\Users\osbieh\Desktop\JDBC-Test\MySql_JDBC_OLD\build\mysql-connector-java-5.1.6
 [copy] Copied 33 empty directories to 3 empty directories under C:\Users\osbieh\Desktop\JDBC-Test\MySql_JDBC_OLD\build\mysql-connector-java-5.1.6
 [copy] Copying 15 files to C:\Users\osbieh\Desktop\JDBC-Test\MySql_JDBC_OLD\build\mysql-connector-java-5.1.6
-init-no-crypto:

init:
[mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\osbieh\Desktop\JDBC-Test\MySql_JDBC_OLD\build\mysql-connector-java-5.1.6\lib-nodist

-clean-output:
compile-driver-jdbc3:
[javac] C:\Users\osbieh\Desktop\JDBC-Test\MySql_JDBC_OLD\build.xml:724: warning:'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; setto false for repeatable builds
[javac] Compiling 132 source files to C:\Users\osbieh\Desktop\JDBC-Test\MySql_JDBC_OL\build\mysql-connector-java-5.1.6
[javac] C:\Users\osbieh\Desktop\JDBC-Test\MySql_JDBC_OLD\build\mysql-connectorjava-5.1.6\com\mysql\jdbc\LoadBalancingConnectionProxy.java:413: warning: non
-varargs call of varargs method with inexact argument type for last parameter;
[javac]                             return ((Long) getLocalTimeMethod.invoke(null, null))
[javac]
   ^
[javac]   cast to Object for a varargs call
[javac]   cast to Object[] for a non-varargs call and to suppress this warning
[javac] C:\Users\osbieh\Desktop\JDBC-Test\MySql_JDBC_OLD\build\mysql-connector-java-5.1.6\com\mysql\jdbc\StatementImpl.java:65: error: StatementImpl is notabstract and does not override abstract method isCloseOnCompletion() in Statement
[javac] public class StatementImpl implements Statement {
[javac]        ^
[javac] C:\Users\osbieh\Desktop\JDBC-Test\MySql_JDBC_OLD\build\mysql-connector-java-5.1.6\com\mysql\jdbc\PreparedStatement.java:85: error: com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement is not abstract and does not override abstract methodsetSQLXML(int,SQLXML) in java.sql.PreparedStatement
[javac] public class PreparedStatement extends com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl
implements
[javac]        ^
[javac] C:\Users\osbieh\Desktop\JDBC-Test\MySql_JDBC_OLD\build\mysql-connector-java-5.1.6\com\mysql\jdbc\ConnectionImpl.java:74: error: ConnectionImpl is not abstract and does not override abstract method getNetworkTimeout() in Connection
[javac] public class ConnectionImpl extends ConnectionPropertiesImpl implements
[javac]        ^
[javac] C:\Users\osbieh\Desktop\JDBC-Test\MySql_JDBC_OLD\build\mysql-connector-java-5.1.6\com\mysql\jdbc\CallableStatement.java:55: error: com.mysql.jdbc.CallableStatement is not abstract and does not override abstract method<T>getObject(String,Class<T>) in java.sql.CallableStatement
[javac] public class CallableStatement extends PreparedStatement implements
[javac]        ^
[javac]   where T is a type-variable:
[javac]     T extends Object declared in method <T>getObject(String,Class<T>)
[javac] C:\Users\osbieh\Desktop\JDBC-Test\MySql_JDBC_OLD\build\mysql-connectorjava-5.1.6\com\mysql\jdbc\ResultSetImpl.java:120: error: ResultSetImpl is notabstract and doesnot override abstract method <T>getObject(String,Class<T>) inResultSet
[javac] public class ResultSetImpl implements ResultSetInternalMethods {
[javac]        ^
[javac]   where T is a type-variable:
[javac]     T extends Object declared in method <T>getObject(String,Class<T>)
[javac] C:\Users\osbieh\Desktop\JDBC-Test\MySql_JDBC_OLD\build\mysql-connectorjava5.1.6\com\mysql\jdbc\DatabaseMetaData.java:64: error: com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData is notabstract and does not override abstract method generatedKeyAlwaysReturned() in java.sql.DatabaseMetaData
[javac] public class DatabaseMetaData implements java.sql.DatabaseMetaData {

[javac]        ^
[javac] C:\Users\osbieh\Desktop\JDBC-Test\MySql_JDBC_OLD\build\mysql-connector-java-5.1.6\com\mysql\jdbc\NonRegisteringDriver.java:67: error: NonRegistering
Driver is not abstract and does not override abstract method getParentLogger() in Driver
[javac] public class NonRegisteringDriver implements java.sql.Driver {
[javac]        ^
[javac] C:\Users\osbieh\Desktop\JDBC-Test\MySql_JDBC_OLD\build\mysql-connector-java-5.1.6\com\mysql\jdbc\Driver.java:53: error: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver is not abstract and does not override abstract method getParentLogger() in java.sql.Driver
[javac] public class Driver extends NonRegisteringDriver implements java.sql.Driver {
[javac]        ^
[javac] C:\Users\osbieh\Desktop\JDBC-Test\MySql_JDBC_OLD\build\mysql-connector-java-5.1.6\com\mysql\jdbc\ReplicationConnection.java:45: error: ReplicationConnection is not abstract and does not override abstract method getNetworkTimeout() in Connection
[javac] public class ReplicationConnection implements Connection, PingTarget
{
[javac]        ^
[javac] C:\Users\osbieh\Desktop\JDBC-Test\MySql_JDBC_OLD\build\mysql-connector-java-5.1.6\com\mysql\jdbc\ReplicationDriver.java:54: error: ReplicationDriveris not abstract and does not override abstract method getParentLogger() in Driver
[javac] public class ReplicationDriver extends NonRegisteringReplicationDriver
[javac]        ^
[javac] C:\Users\osbieh\Desktop\JDBC-Test\MySql_JDBC_OLD\build\mysql-connector-java-5.1.6\com\mysql\jdbc\StringUtils.java:100: warning: non-varargs call of varargs method with inexact argument type for last parameter;
[javac]                             return (String) toPlainStringMethod.invoke(decimal, null);
[javac]
        ^
[javac]   cast to Object for a varargs call
[javac]   cast to Object[] for a non-varargs call and to suppress this warning
[javac] C:\Users\osbieh\Desktop\JDBC-Test\MySql_JDBC_OLD\build\mysql-connectorjava5.1.6\com\mysql\jdbc\Util.java:54: warning: non-varargs call of varargs method with inexact argument type for last parameter;
[javac]                     systemNanoTimeMethod = System.class.getMethod("nanoTime",null);
[javac]
      ^
[javac]   cast to Class<?> for a varargs call
[javac]   cast to Class<?>[] for a non-varargs call and to suppress this warning
[javac] C:\Users\osbieh\Desktop\JDBC-Test\MySql_JDBC_OLD\build\mysql-connector java-5.1.6\com\mysql\jdbc\Util.java:447: warning: non-varargs call of varargs method with inexact argument type for last parameter;
[javac]                     return networkInterfaceClass.getMethod("getByName", null).invoke(
[javac]
^
[javac]   cast to Class for a varargs call
[javac]   cast to Class[] for a non-varargs call and to suppress this warning
[javac] C:\Users\osbieh\Desktop\JDBC-Test\MySql_JDBC_OLD\build\mysql-connector-java-5.1.6\com\mysql\jdbc\Util.java:477: warning: non-varargs call of varargs method with inexact argument type for last parameter;
[javac]                             return ((Long) systemNanoTimeMethod.invoke(null, null))
[javac]
     ^
[javac]   cast to Object for a varargs call
[javac]   cast to Object[] for a non-varargs call and to suppress this warning
[javac] C:\Users\osbieh\Desktop\JDBC-Test\MySql_JDBC_OLD\build\mysql-connector-java-5.1.6\com\mysql\jdbc\jdbc2\optional\StatementWrapper.java:46: error: StatementWrapper is not abstract and does not override abstract method isCloseOnCompletion() in Statement
[javac] public class StatementWrapper extends WrapperBase implements Statement {
 [javac]        ^
[javac] C:\Users\osbieh\Desktop\JDBC-Test\MySql_JDBC_OLD\build\mysql-connector-java-5.1.6\com\mysql\jdbc\jdbc2\optional\PreparedStatementWrapper.java:58: error: PreparedStatementWrapper is not abstract and does not override abstract method setNClob(int,Reader) in PreparedStatement
[javac] public class PreparedStatementWrapper extends StatementWrapper implements
[javac]        ^
[javac] C:\Users\osbieh\Desktop\JDBC-Test\MySql_JDBC_OLD\build\mysql-connector-java-5.1.6\com\mysql\jdbc\jdbc2\optional\CallableStatementWrapper.java:53: error: CallableStatementWrapper is not abstract and does not override abstract method <T>getObject(String,Class<T>) in CallableStatement
[javac] public class CallableStatementWrapper extends PreparedStatementWrapper
[javac]        ^
[javac]   where T is a type-variable:
[javac]     T extends Object declared in method <T>getObject(String,Class<T>)
[javac] C:\Users\osbieh\Desktop\JDBC-Test\MySql_JDBC_OLD\build\mysql-connector-java-5.1.6\com\mysql\jdbc\jdbc2\optional\ConnectionWrapper.java:62: error: ConnectionWrapper is not abstract and does not override abstract method getNetworkTimeout() in Connection
[javac] public class ConnectionWrapper extends WrapperBase implements Connection {
[javac]        ^
[javac] C:\Users\osbieh\Desktop\JDBC-Test\MySql_JDBC_OLD\build\mysql-connector-java-5.1.6\com\mysql\jdbc\jdbc2\optional\MysqlPooledConnection.java:50: error: MysqlPooledConnection is not abstract and does not override abstract method removeStatementEventListener(StatementEventListener) in PooledConnection
[javac] public class MysqlPooledConnection implements PooledConnection {
[javac]        ^
[javac] C:\Users\osbieh\Desktop\JDBC-Test\MySql_JDBC_OLD\build\mysql-connector-java-5.1.6\com\mysql\jdbc\jdbc2\optional\MysqlDataSource.java:46: error: MysqlDataSourceis not abstract and does not override abstract method getParentLogger() in CommonDataSource
[javac] public class MysqlDataSource extends ConnectionPropertiesImpl implements
[javac]        ^
[javac] C:\Users\osbieh\Desktop\JDBC-Test\MySql_JDBC_OLD\build\mysql-connector-java-5.1.6\com\mysql\jdbc\jdbc2\optional\MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource.java:44: error: MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource is not abstract and does not override abstract method getParentLogger() in CommonDataSource
[javac] public class MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource extends MysqlDataSource implements
[javac]        ^
[javac] C:\Users\osbieh\Desktop\JDBC-Test\MySql_JDBC_OLD\build\mysql-connector-java-5.1.6\com\mysql\jdbc\jdbc2\optional\MysqlXAConnection.java:65: error: MysqlXAConnection is not abstract and does not override abstract method removeStatementEventListener(StatementEventListener) in PooledConnection
[javac] public class MysqlXAConnection extends MysqlPooledConnection implements
[javac]        ^
[javac] C:\Users\osbieh\Desktop\JDBC-Test\MySql_JDBC_OLD\build\mysql-connector-java-5.1.6\com\mysql\jdbc\jdbc2\optional\MysqlXADataSource.java:39: error: MysqlXADataSource is not abstract and does not override abstract method getParentLogger() in CommonDataSource
[javac] public class MysqlXADataSource extends MysqlDataSource implements
[javac]        ^
[javac] C:\Users\osbieh\Desktop\JDBC-Test\MySql_JDBC_OLD\build\mysql-connector-java-5.1.6\com\mysql\jdbc\jdbc2\optional\SuspendableXAConnection.java:17: error: SuspendableXAConnection is not abstract and does not override abstract method removeStatementEventListener(StatementEventListener) in PooledConnection
[javac] public class SuspendableXAConnection extends MysqlPooledConnection implements
[javac]        ^
[javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
[javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[javac] 20 errors
[javac] 5 warnings

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\osbieh\Desktop\JDBC-Test\MySql_JDBC_OLD\build.xml:724: Compile failed;
```

Comment: Is there any possible solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You did not mention which version of Connector/J you are using.  The [version 5.1](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html) has implementation of those [additional interface methods](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?3,559877,559877).

Comment: I'm using Connector/J 5.1.6 ( mysql-connector-java-5.1.6 )

Comment: The forum link mentions version `5.1.21` to have this additional implementation. The latest available download is `5.1.27`.

Comment: I tried 5.1.27 but I can't know what is the ant command to build it, I tried. ant package but it is give me this error : Buildfile: C:\Users\osbieh\Desktop\JDBC-Test\mysql-connector-java-5.1.27\build.xml
     [echo] Compiling class files to bin...
  [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml. It could not be found.
-compiler-check:

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\osbieh\Desktop\JDBC-Test\mysql-connector-java-5.1.27\build.xml:125: Problem: failed to create task or type if
Cause: The name is undefined.